# Issue with titlesec page styles and appendix in book class

Tags: header-footer, appendices, titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` to set my page style in a book class. If I include an appendix, the header corresponding to the first chapter is "Appendix 1" instead of "Chapter 1".

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}  
\newpagestyle{main}[\scshape]{%
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle]
  {\ifthesection{\thesection\space\,\sectiontitle}
  {\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{main}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum

\appendix
\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `\cleardoublepage` before `\appendix`; probably a bad interaction between `titlesec` and the class.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}  
\newpagestyle{main}[\scshape]{%
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle]
  {\ifthesection{\thesection\space\,\sectiontitle}
  {\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{main}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\appendix

\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`titlesec`/`titleps` doesn't set `\chaptertitlename` as a "marked" command. Perhaps it should. For the time being, just write:

```
\newtitlemark{\chaptertitlename}
```